# Difference between jersey-media-json-jackson, jersey-json,jersey-media-multipart?

Tags: java, xml, rest, jackson, jersey-2.0

I want to develop one web api,that will produce and consume both **JSON** and **XML** data.

I have used **JAXB** for **XML** support and it is working fine.
Now i want to add JSON type.i studied different tutorial, all are using different dependencies as below:

1. jersey-media-json-jackson
2. jersey-json
3. jersey-media-multipart

please help me whcih perfect and which support both XML and JSON.
what is difference between them all?

Comment: check this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Jersey-Media-Json-Jackson**

Jackson JSON processor could be controlled via providing a `custom Jackson 2` `ObjectMapper` (or ObjectMapper for Jackson 1) instance. This could be handy if you need to redefine the default Jackson behaviour and to fine-tune how your JSON data structures look like. Detailed description of all Jackson features is out of scope of this guide. The example below gives you a hint on how to wire your `ObjectMapper (ObjectMapper)` instance into your Jersey application.

In order to use Jackson as your `JSON (JAXB/POJO)` provider you need to register JacksonFeature (Jackson1Feature) and a `ContextResolver<T>` for ObjectMapper,

**2.** **Jersey-Json :**

Jersey JSON support comes as a set of `JAX-RS MessageBodyReader<T>` and `MessageBodyWriter<T>` providers distributed with jersey-json module. These providers enable using three basic approaches when working with JSON format:

```
POJO support

JAXB based JSON support

Low-level, JSONObject/JSONArray based JSON support
```

**3. Jersey-media-multipart**

The multipart in this module provide an integration of `multipart/*` request and response bodies in a `JAX-RS runtime environment`. The set of registered providers is leveraged, in that the content type for a body part of such a message reuses the same `MessageBodyReader<T>/MessageBodyWriter<T>` implementations as would be used for that content type as a standalone entity.

The following `list of general MIME MultiPart` features is currently supported:

- The MIME-Version: 1.0 HTTP header is included on generated responses.
  It is accepted, but not required, on processed requests.
- A MessageBodyReader implementation for consuming MIME MultiPart
  entities.
- A MessageBodyWriter implementation for producing MIME MultiPart
  entities. The appropriate @Provider is used to serialize each body
  part, based on its media type.
- Optional creation of an appropriate boundary parameter on a generated
  Content-Type header, if not already present.